# How to throw exception when no case is match in switch

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

I have a function that have switch block I want to throw exception when nothing match how can I do that I wrote this switch

```
private static int ClimateCal() {
    int climateCal = 0;
    switch (climate.toLowerCase()){
        case "Hot":
            climateCal = 0;
            break;
        case "Cold":
            climateCal = 250;
            break;
        case "Moderate":
            climateCal = 500;
            break;
        default:
            Exception exception;
    }
    return climateCal;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same way you'd throw an exception any other time.

```
switch (condition){
    case "A":
        //do something
        break;
    case "B":
        //do something
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception("oh no"); // or IllegalStateException or something
}
```

I'm only guessing, but you probably want to catch this further up the chain, so change the signature of your method to propagate the exception:

```
private static int ClimateCal() throws Exception
```

---

If there is a constraint that the climate can only be one of a finite set of values then really you should try to enforce this constraint at compile-time rather than run-time. I would declare an enum to represent the possible values:

```
enum Temperature
{
    HOT      (0),
    COLD     (250),
    MODERATE (500);

    private final int cal;

    Temperature(final int cal)
    {
        this.cal = cal;
    }

    public int getCal()
    {
        return cal;
    }
}
```

You could flesh this out further, obviously.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
private static int ClimateCal() throws Exception {         // Add throws keyword here If you want to catch the exception by the calling method.
    int climateCal = 0;
    switch (climate.toLowerCase()){
        case "Hot":
            climateCal = 0;
            break;
        case "Cold":
            climateCal = 250;
            break;
        case "Moderate":
            climateCal = 500;
            break;
        default:
            throw new Exception();
    }
    return climateCal;
}
```

Comment: and method signature would be throws?

Comment: Yes, If you want to catch the exception elsewhere.

Comment: I'm getting "Hot" in climate but noting is matching and throwing exception

Comment: @blackHawk that is because you have `climate.toLowerCase()` and in `case "Hot":`. It should be `case "hot":`. Note all letters are small.

Comment: @Michael you are ofcourse right, thankyou. I accidentally undid the change I made earlier to add `throws Exception`. I was in a hurry! :D

Comment: Yes I think im also in hurry too, thank you for pointing out, also could you tell me how can i change 2.34566 to 2.3

Comment: @blackHawk I could but I'd rather you google it first. There are some good answers on SO too. Also don't forget to mark my answer correct if it solved your problem.